# Restart automatically context variables

Tags: chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

It is possible to configure the ibm chatbot so that automatically when you restart it, the context variables are deleted.

Comment: What do you mean by "restart"?

Comment: Normally, when you start a new conversation with a chatbot the context variables are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption - restart when it reaches desired node 
You can make the contents values `""` in the node where one conversation ends (for eg- #goodbye node or where some process ends in a node).